# Mixing Jinja2 and Angular2 Templates

Tags: python, angular, jinja2

I am trying to user Jinja2 and Angular2 templates together.

I have successfully used Flask and AngularJS together in the past.

```
JINJA_ENVIRONMENT = jinja2.Environment(
  loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader( os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'dist') ),
  extensions = ['jinja2.ext.autoescape'],
  autoescape = True,

  block_start_string = '<%',
  block_end_string = '%>',
  variable_start_string = '%%',
  variable_end_string = '%%',
  comment_start_string = '<#',
  comment_end_string = '#>'
)
```

Angular would use `{{ example }}` and Jinja would use `%% example %%`.

So far my results are showing the angular template works fine but Jinja wont work at all

What on earth am I doing wrong.

Comment: Is it possible that having `variable_start_string` and `variable_end_string` as the same string could cause a problem? (Does it work if you have `(%` and `%)` instead, for example?)

Comment: I got it, Jinja works fine, but only in Angular's main index.html file, not in any components. Silly me.